# php echo results in alphabetical order

Tags: php

This code below will echo the keyword in each file, Is it possible to get the results (Keyword from each file) to display in alphabetical order.

```
<?php 
$files = (glob('{beauty,careers,education,entertainment,pets}/*.php', GLOB_BRACE)); 

    $selection = $files;
    $files = array();

    $keywords = $matches[1];

    foreach ($selection as $file) {    
    if (basename($file) == 'index.php') continue;
    if (basename($file) == 'error_log') continue;
    $files[] = $file;    
}
    foreach($files as $file) {
        $title = str_replace('-', ' ', pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_FILENAME));

    $content = file_get_contents($file);
    if (!$content) {

        echo "error reading file $file<br>";
    }
    else {
        preg_match("/keywords = \"(.*?)\"/i", $content, $matches);
        $keywords = $matches[1];
    }
        $results .= '<li><a href="http://domain.com/' . htmlentities($file, ENT_QUOTES) . '">'.$keywords.'</a></li>';    
}
?>
<?=$results?>
```

Comment: are they keywords space separated, comma separated?

Comment: You should indent your code properly.

Comment: there is only 1 keyword in each file and they are echoed in ul li and float left.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`sort()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php) to sort the keyword array:

```
$keywords = array();

// ...

$keywords[] = $matches[1];
sort($keywords);
```

Comment: Warning: sort() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in /home/what/public_html/a.php on line 18

Comment: Make sure you put the keywords in an array first. Updated code should point you in the right direction

Comment: Still the same error on line 12 now, I'm still learning php so its probably my code that's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

use sort() on $keywords.  There's some spelling mistakes and unused varaibles.  You need to not build your $results HTML until all the files are processes, so move that $results = '' out of the foreach loop that processes the files, then sort, then foreach the keywords and build up $results.

```
<?php 
$selection = (glob('{beauty,careers,education,entertainment,pets}/*.php', GLOB_BRACE)); 

$files = array();

// $keywords = $matches[1];

foreach ($selection as $file) {      
    if (basename($file) == 'index.php') continue;
    if (basename($file) == 'error_log') continue;
    $files[] = $file;      
} 

foreach($files as $file) { 
    //$title = str_replace('-', ' ', pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_FILENAME));

    $content = file_get_contents($file);
    if (!$content) { 

        echo "error reading file $file<br>";
    } 
    else { 
        preg_match("/keywords = \"(.*?)\"/i", $content, $matches);
        $keywords[] = $matches[1];
    } 
} 

$results = '';
sort($keywords); //comment this out to see the effects of the sort()
foreach($keywords as $_k) { 
    $results .= '<li><a href="http://domain.com/' . htmlentities($file, ENT_QUOTES) . '">'.$_k.'</a></li>';      
} 
?>
<?=$results?>
```

Comment: Thanks for trying but it doesn't display anything? the good thing is there are also no errors.

Comment: It won't display anything unless you have the directory structure you defined with the glob() function in place.  If it doesn't display anything then there are no files with keywords=" " in them.